# Windows FFmpeg converting imges into a gif with correct framerate

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, gif, frame-rate

I've been using **ffmpeg** to create animated gif images from images.

Every time I use this command;

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 120 -f concat -i images.txt ffmpeg.gif
```

the output file it produces is way slower than 120 frames per second.

Is there something I'm missing to set the gif's fps to 120 instead of 1?

```
Output #0, gif, to 'ffmpeg.gif':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, pal8, 468x60, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 120 fps, 100 tbn, 120 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 gif
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> gif (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 3, current: 3; changing to 4. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4, current: 4; changing to 5. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 5, current: 5; changing to 6. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6, current: 6; changing to 7. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 7, current: 7; changing to 8. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 8, current: 8; changing to 9. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 9, current: 8; changing to 10. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 10, current: 9; changing to 11. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 11, current: 10; changing to 12. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 12, current: 11; changing to 13. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 13, current: 12; changing to 14. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 14, current: 13; changing to 15. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 15, current: 13; changing to 16. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 16, current: 14; changing to 17. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17, current: 15; changing to 18. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 18, current: 16; changing to 19. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 19, current: 17; changing to 20. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 20, current: 18; changing to 21. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 21, current: 18; changing to 22. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 22, current: 19; changing to 23. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 23, current: 20; changing to 24. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 24, current: 21; changing to 25. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 25, current: 22; changing to 26. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 26, current: 23; changing to 27. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 27, current: 23; changing to 28. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 28, current: 24; changing to 29. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 29, current: 25; changing to 30. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 30, current: 26; changing to 31. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 31, current: 27; changing to 32. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 32, current: 28; changing to 33. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 33, current: 28; changing to 34. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 34, current: 29; changing to 35. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 35, current: 30; changing to 36. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 36, current: 31; changing to 37. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 37, current: 32; changing to 38. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 38, current: 33; changing to 39. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 39, current: 33; changing to 40. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 40, current: 34; changing to 41. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 41, current: 35; changing to 42. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 42, current: 36; changing to 43. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 43, current: 37; changing to 44. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 44, current: 38; changing to 45. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 45, current: 38; changing to 46. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 46, current: 39; changing to 47. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 47, current: 40; changing to 48. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 48, current: 41; changing to 49. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 49, current: 42; changing to 50. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 50, current: 43; changing to 51. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 51, current: 43; changing to 52. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 52, current: 44; changing to 53. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 53, current: 45; changing to 54. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 54, current: 46; changing to 55. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 55, current: 47; changing to 56. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 56, current: 48; changing to 57. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 57, current: 48; changing to 58. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 58, current: 49; changing to 59. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 59, current: 50; changing to 60. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 60, current: 51; changing to 61. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 61, current: 52; changing to 62. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 62, current: 53; changing to 63. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 63, current: 53; changing to 64. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 64, current: 54; changing to 65. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 65, current: 55; changing to 66. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 66, current: 56; changing to 67. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 67, current: 57; changing to 68. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 68, current: 58; changing to 69. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 69, current: 58; changing to 70. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 70, current: 59; changing to 71. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 71, current: 60; changing to 72. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 72, current: 61; changing to 73. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 73, current: 62; changing to 74. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 74, current: 63; changing to 75. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 75, current: 63; changing to 76. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 76, current: 64; changing to 77. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 77, current: 65; changing to 78. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 78, current: 66; changing to 79. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 79, current: 67; changing to 80. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 80, current: 68; changing to 81. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 81, current: 68; changing to 82. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 82, current: 69; changing to 83. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 83, current: 70; changing to 84. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 84, current: 71; changing to 85. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85, current: 72; changing to 86. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 86, current: 73; changing to 87. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 87, current: 73; changing to 88. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 88, current: 74; changing to 89. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 89, current: 75; changing to 90. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 90, current: 76; changing to 91. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 91, current: 77; changing to 92. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 92, current: 78; changing to 93. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 93, current: 78; changing to 94. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 94, current: 79; changing to 95. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 95, current: 80; changing to 96. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 96, current: 81; changing to 97. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 97, current: 82; changing to 98. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 98, current: 83; changing to 99. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[gif @ 000000a80e3694e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 99, current: 83; changing to 100. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  101 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=     245kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=1985.2kbits/s speed=4.84x
video:243kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.646120%
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 120 -f concat -i images.txt -r 120 ffmpeg.gif
```

If not, then rename the images to form a naming sequence i.e. `img00001.png`, `img00002.png`...

and run

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 120 -i ima%05d.png ffmpeg.gif
```

Comment: Option -framerate not found. What does that mean?

Comment: With the concat command? It means ffmpeg does not recgnize the input as an image pipe. Rename and use the 2nd command.

Comment: How can I put all images in a folder as an -i? I have PvP0000.png to PvP0100.png

Comment: pvpC:\Users\Max\Documents\s\PvP\ffmpeg.bat4d.png: Protocol not found
I don't know if I'm just an idiot or if there is something wrong.

Comment: Are you executing a BAT file? If yes, say so! Use `-i pvp%%04d.png` in that case.

Comment: ffmpeg.exe -framerate 120 -r 120 -i pvp%%04d.png ffmpeg.gif
It is still very slow

Comment: How can I paste a large output file into a comment? Is there anyway we can msg or some way?

Comment: Edit it into the question.

Comment: Sheesh. GIFs go only upto 50 fps in some browsers and 20 fps in others. See [here](http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16524517190/animated-gif-minimum-frame-delay-browser)

Comment: Oh! Okay, I understand my limitations. Thanks for helping me out!